# e[i].render is not a function fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using undo and redo function, when I undo/redo the object's position(z-index) is change, I didn't found any way the save the z-index to JSON(`toJSON`). So I try to set the z-index on undo/redo function.

```
...
var jsonData = JSON.parse(config.canvasState[config.currentStateIndex+1]);
if(jsonData.objects.length){
       jsonData.objects.forEach(function(e){
              if(e && e.selectable === false){
                     canvas.sendToBack(e);
              }
       })
}
canvas.renderAll();
...
```

I get the error `e[i].render is not a function`.

**Solution**

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(config.canvasState[config.currentStateIndex+1]);
var imgObjs = _canvas.getObjects();
if(imgObjs.length){
       imgObjs.forEach(function(e){
              if(e && e.selectable === false){
                     _canvas.sendToBack(e);
              }
       });
}
```

Comment: There is no `e[i].render()` call in the code you posted. The error must stem from somewhere else.

Comment: The error point to the line `canvas.sendToBack(e)`

Comment: which fabricjs version are you using?

Comment: fabricjs version 1.7.17

Comment: instead of using `jsonData.objects`,  use `canvas.getObjects()` to iterate over drawn elements. http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#getObjects

Comment: Ya, you're right. Can do in this simple way, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `JSON.parse(config.canvasState[config.currentStateIndex+1]);` creates *copies* of all the instances of elements in the canvas. When you run `.forEach` on those copies and try to render them using fabric, you're operating on elements that *don't exist in the canvas* and therefore can't call `sendToBack` on them.

I would recommend seeing if there's an alternate way of getting the list of elements on the canvas. Something like `canvas._objects.forEach(...)` would probably work.

Comment: Use [canvas#forEachObject](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#forEachObject)

Answer (score 0):

This was just happening to me in Fabric 3.6

The issue was that one of the objects being added to fabric was an HTML element rather than a "fabric object".  Fixing the reference cleared up the issue where Fabric is expecting .render() to be there when it's the right type of object.